# Can you download an image from an <img> element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, download

I am trying to download an image element on a webpage that is dynamically set using the use-react-screenshot library. Because of this I cannot download the image using a file name or link, so I have been attempting to download it based on the image element id.

Currently what I have is

```
 var ss = document.createElement('a');
 ss.setAttribute('href', "#screenshot");
 ss.setAttribute('download', fileName);
 ss.style.display = 'none';
 document.body.appendChild(ss);
 ss.click();
 document.body.removeChild(ss);
```

where screenshot is the id of the image element containing the image I want to download

Is it even possible to do this or should I use some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-use-screenshot` gives you the [dataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) of the image, either using the first value returned by the hook or the resolved value in the promise when using `takeScreenShot` func, so you just have to pass it as `href`

```js
import { useScreenshot, createFileName } from "use-react-screenshot";

const [image, takeScreenShot] = useScreenshot({ type: "image/jpeg" });
// ...
const download = (image, params) => {
  const ss = document.createElement('a');
  ss.href = image;
  ss.download = createFileName(params.extension, 'myfilename'); 
  ss.click();
  // notice you don't need to append the element to the DOM to trigger the download
};

const downloadScreenshot = () => takeScreenShot(ref.current).then(download);
```